# Comparação DateTime em agendamento no banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados

Preciso de uma luz. Estou criando um sistema de agendamento de viagens de viaturas e preciso que antes de incluir uma nova viagem, que seja conferido se a data e hora início da viagem e a data e hora final da viagem já não foram ocupadas, usando essa viatura que está como FK e esse motorista que está como FK.

Ou seja preciso que antes que a viagem seja incluída, saber se aquela viatura **E** o motorista **E** a data e hora estão disponíveis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou supor que `:data_inicio` e `:data_fim` sejam os timestamps da viagem que você quer marcar, com o motorista de id `:idm` e veículo `:idv`.

Vou supor também que as suas tabelas são `viagem`, `motorista` e `viatura`, sendo que `motorista` e `viatura` têm um campo `id` em cada sendo chave primária e que `viagem` tenha os campos `id_motorista` e `id_veiculo`. Na tabela `viagem` também temos as colunas `inicio` e `fim`, que são timestamps. Todos esses campos são `NOT NULL`.

```sql
SELECT g.*
FROM viagem g
INNER JOIN motorista m ON g.id_motorista = m.id
INNER JOIN viatura v ON g.id_viatura = v.id
WHERE (m.id = :idm OR v.id = :idv)
AND NOT (g.inicio > :data_fim)
AND NOT (g.fim < :data_inicio)
```

Essa consulta vai trazer como resultado as viagens que estarão colidindo com aquela que você quer cadastrar. Ela funciona procurando por viagens com:

- O mesmo motorista **OU** a mesma viatura.
- Que não têm início depois da data/hora que acaba a viagem que você quer cadastrar
- Que não têm término antes da data/hora que começa a viagem que você quer cadastrar.

Essas duas últimas condições são a parte mais importante, porque se a viagem que você quer cadastrar termina antes de começar a já cadastrada ou começa depois de terminar a já cadastrada, então ela não colide. Caso contrário, decerto houve uma colisão de horários.

Comment: Victor demais sua ajuda, já vou testar ela, estou no 3 semestre da faculdade, adorando, mas é complicado pegar essa lógica, obrigado pela ajuda. Como estou fazendo esse seminario só com BD, você recomendaria uma Trigger para tratar esse Insert?

p.s. cara você deu uma luz no fim do tunel e não é um trem kkkkkk

Comment: @MauricioKalfelz Não. Não recomendaria usar trigger para isso. Provavelmente até funcionaria e até seria razoavelmente fácil de fazer, mas em geral é melhor colocar as regras de negócio na aplicação e deixar o banco de dados apenas para guardar os dados. Embora você esteja fazendo o seminário só com o BD, não há como fugir do fato de que um BD sem uma aplicação não tem muita serventia.

Comment: Victor, bom dia, vocês tem razão mesmo isso deveria ser feito na aplicação, mas como disse além de eu ser um iniciante, praticamente um bebê nessa área, estou tendo muita dificuldade, e vou precisar criar essas regra dentro do DB, no próximo seminário do semestre que vem que colocaremos BD com o front, dai vou passar as regras para a aplicação. Muito obrigado por sua ajuda, vou tentar fazer o restante da Trigger

Comment: Victor peguei o que você me explicou e tenteif azer algo, mas nao deu nem de perto certo quase desistindo